# Encounter error when install Google Cloud Client Library for Python on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My AWS EC2 (default linux) is running python 2.7 and I'm using:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

to install Google Cloud Client Library for Python. But I get this error:

```
Cannot uninstall 'chardet'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to install `google-cloud`, that package [is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/).

As you have tagged this as Storage also, I assume you intend to use GCS from Python: rather install [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) with `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`. It is also recommended to use [virtualenv](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#linux).